"emitWarning is not a function" when trying to authenticate with google-auth-library
I'm trying to get two Cloud Run services in the same VPC to communicate with each other. I'm following this tutorial. The section I linked is the one I'm having problems with. The faulty code right now looks like this:
    import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';
    const auth = new GoogleAuth();
    
    client: any;
    clientHeaders: any;
    
    serviceUrl = "https://url"
    headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    };
    
    async setup() {
        try {
            if (!this.client)
                this.client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(this.serviceUrl); // error happens here
            const gcloudHeaders = await this.client.getRequestHeaders();
            this.headers = {
                ...gcloudHeaders,
                ...this.headers,
            };
            const res = await this.client.request({ url: this.serviceUrl });
            console.info(res.data);
        } catch (err) {
            throw Error(
                'could not create an identity token: ' + err.message
            );
        }
    }

This code throws the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: could not create an identity token: o.emitWarning is not a function
at p.setup

Looking into it, it seems to be a nodeJS issue, possibly inside google-auth-library. Googling the issue doesn't give me many results, and none speficic to google-auth-library. Versions:
nodeJS v20.10.0 
google-auth-library ^9.7.0

Any ideas?

const res = await this.client.request({ url: this.serviceUrl });
In the above line, I don't see where you've used the headers which is supposed to include the authorization (token that was generated for you).
In the example that you're following (which is using got), you'll notice this line
const serviceResponse = await got(serviceUrl, serviceRequestOptions);

In that example, their call to the service URL includes the serviceRequestOptions which includes the headers they retrieved by calling getRequestHeaders
